# I want my login button to be centered and i tried but didn t work. What to do?

Tags: react-native

```js
const stile = StyleSheet.create({
  loginButtonn: {
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    borderRadius: 30,
    height: 44,
    marginTop: 30,
    width: 326,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center'
  },
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't very well written question, but I can try to answer it.

There are multiple ways of trying to achieve what you are trying to do. My favorite way is to use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/), which it looks like you tried to do. You can take a look at the link but here's what you're missing; (Basically just a parent element with `display` of `flex`)

```js
const style = StyleSheet.create({
    loginButton: {
        backgroundColor: "#fff",
        borderRadius: 30,
        height: 44,
        marginTop: 30,
        width: 326, 
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    },
    container: {
        display: 'flex',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%'
    }
});
```

In render function (something like):

```html
<div className={style.container}>
    <button className={style.loginButton} />
</div>
```